# Failed to load API definition Fetch Error, when deployed but fine on localhost

Tags: azure-devops, swagger, swagger-ui

I am upgrading my api from netcore2.1 to 3.1

When I run on localhost the UI works fine.

When I deploy via Azure DevOps and go to the myapplication/myapi/swagger.html url I get

```
Failed to load API definition 
Fetch Error
Service Unavailable /myapi/swagger/v1/swagger/json
```

Yet I can see the json  at

```
myapplication/myapi/swagger/v1/swagger.json
```

I have the following

```
   public static IApplicationBuilder UseSwaggerDocumentation(this IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseSwagger(c =>

            c.RouteTemplate = "myapi/swagger/{documentName}/swagger.json"
        );

        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {

            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/myapi/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Versioned API v1.0");

            c.RoutePrefix = "myapi/swagger";

        });

        return app;
    }
```

I am using

```
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore (5.2.0)
```

Comment: I read somewhere that iis Express behaves differently than IIS 8.5

Answer (score 1):

I found the following worked.

```
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseSwaggerDocumentation(this IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseSwagger(c =>

            c.RouteTemplate = "myapi/{documentName}/swagger.json"
        );

        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {

            c.SwaggerEndpoint("./v1/swagger.json", "Versioned API v1.0");

            c.RoutePrefix = "myapi";

        });

        return app;
    }
```

The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) state

> If using directories with IIS or a reverse proxy, set the Swagger
>   endpoint to a relative path using the ./ prefix. For example,
>   ./swagger/v1/swagger.json. Using /swagger/v1/swagger.json instructs
>   the app to look for the JSON file at the true root of the URL (plus
>   the route prefix, if used). For example, use
>   http://localhost://swagger/v1/swagger.json instead
>   of
>   http://localhost:///swagger/v1/swagger.json.

However unfortunately my solution doesn't work with Autorest.
Thus I asked [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60813853/microsoft-openapi-models-openapidocument-serializeasv2-invalid-uri-the-format-o)

Comment: Thanks Lance I feel like I am wrestling an octopus. As soon as I get something working other things fail. Thus I dont want to mark this as answered  just yet,

Comment: I asked for more help at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60819169/fatal-operationid-is-required-for-all-operations-please-add-it-for-get-opera

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60861020/failed-resolving-swagger-json-against-file